# React Native nested navigation's headers

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am currently working on a React Native project and facing some challenges with navigation headers. I aim to create a navigation structure similar to what X has. By default, I'm using a drawer navigation (along with a BottomBarNavigation), but I also need a stack navigator to handle scenarios like opening a post or a profile, similar to what you see in application X. My goal is to keep the stack navigator's header when it appears, and hide the default drawer navigation when the stack navigator is active.

My navigation components:

1. Drawer navigation is on top

```
<NavigationContainer onStateChange={(event) => setShowHeader(event.routes[0].state.routes[1].state.index !== 1) }>
  <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: showHeader}}>
    <Drawer.Screen name={lang.t('Dashboard.Dashboard')} component={BottomTabNavigator}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name={lang.t('Settings.Settings')} component={Settings}/>
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

2. Inside Drawer Navigation I have a BottomBarNavigation

```
const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
   return(
     <BottomTab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown:false }}>
       <BottomTab.Screen name={lang.t('Dashboard.BottomBar.Home')} 
       component={HomeScreen}/>
       <BottomTab.Screen name={lang.t('Dashboard.BottomBar.Order_list')} 
       component={OrderListStackNavigator}/>
     </BottomTab.Navigator>
}
```

3. And finally inside the BottomBarNavigator I have a Stack Navigator.

```
const OrderListStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
       <Stack.Screen name="List" component={List}></Stack.Screen>
       <Stack.Screen name="Create" component={Create}></Stack.Screen>
       <Stack.Screen name="Shop List" component={ShopList}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

So far what I tried is:

1. Pass Drawer Navigator as props to their child all the way down to Stack Navigator, so I can change it's option with the `setOption()` function, but I I encountered the proplem that I can't pass object as a param, at least I get a warning
2. Create a context, so I can get a global state that controls which header should be displayed, but the problem with this was that when I change each navigations options the project reloads, this result some unwanted animation, and also you have to push down button twice what is kinda annoying

At the moment I think the problem comes from the navigation structure

I spend more than a day thinking and trying out things, but nothing seems to work, Any help or idea would help. It's a little but usefull feature what I want to make, and it's kinda annoying that I can't make it work

### UPDATE

I have made some modifications on the structure of the navigations, so their all in the same `JSX` file now

I attempted to use a state to handle the drawer navigation header, which caused an error similar to what happens when I try to use a context, resulting in a page reload and instead of getting to the desired component I got throwen back to the initial page of the StackNavigator, additionally, the drawer header is still visible when it should have disappeared, as you can see in the image as well..

showHeader is true only when I am on the `Create` component!

[image]

Comment: you have the headerShown:false in the stack component, disable that and build on it

Comment: Currently I has, because If I set it to true, than two header will shown, somehow I need to hide first the Drawer header

Comment: No, add the header to each of the screens and make it show, and hide the header on the drawer nav

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed explanation? I'm not entirely sure what you mean., If I remove my drawer nav one of my pages (Settings) will be unreachable, and I have two headers too, one for the bottomNavigation bar and one for the stack

Comment: <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} >
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}>

Answer (score 2):

Listen to navigation state changes with [onStateChange](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#onstatechange) and update the application state to hide/show components. Something like this could work:

```
const [showHeader, setShowHeader] = useState(true);

const getCurrentRoute = (state) => {
  if (state.routes[state.index].state != undefined) {
    return getCurrentRoute(state.routes[state.index].state);
  } else {
    return state.routes[state.index];
  }
}

return (
  <NavigationContainer
    onStateChange={(state) =>
      setShowHeader(!['Create'].includes(getCurrentRoute(state).name))
    }>
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: showHeader }}>
...
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Comment: In the ```NavigationContainer``` I have two ```routeNames```, I can reach just the Drawer.Navigaton props, but the ```Create``` route is iniside another Navigator that I can't reach like this

Comment: I am updated my question, so it contains more details about navigation structure

Comment: You can reach all of them, just follow the nested "routes".

Comment: You were right; I can reach them. Like this: ```setShowHeader(event.routes[0].state.routes[1].state.index !== 1)```, this condition returns true only if I open the ```Create``` component from the StackNavigator. However, when I open it, instead of hiding the Drawer header, seems like the app reloads, I am thrown back to the initial component of the StackNavigator, and the Drawer navigation comes in again